# jQuery set timeout in recurring function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to create a recurring function that executes after 5 seconds. I am using the set timeout function but it doesn't seem to execute at all.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    var words   = ["Crear","Evolucionar","Sanar","perdonar","Volver a amar","Brillar"];
    

    var i = 0;

    function Rotate(i)
    {
        

        jQuery( "#fade-text" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {

            jQuery( "#fade-text" ).html(words[i])
            jQuery( "#fade-text" ).fadeIn( "slow" , function(){

                i = i + 1

                console.log(i)
                if(i == words.length )
                    i = 0;

                 setTimeout(Rotate(i), 5000);
                
            });

        }); 

    }

setTimeout(Rotate(i), 50000000);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#syntax), you do not provide the function arguments within the function declaration, instead this comes after the interval.

```js
setTimeout(Rotate, 5000, i);
```